# How to redeem Apple ID balance

Tags: apple-id

I am a resident in India. I have an iPhone 12. Inadvertantly I have landed up with ₹ 600 in my Apple ID balance. I don't purchase any apps or music on iTunes or Apple Store. Is there any other way I can utilise my balance or transfer it ???

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other way I can utilise my balance or transfer it ???

**No**.

The linked Apple Support document answers your query formally:

- https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202359

> ## If you have Apple Account balance that you can't use
>
> You can't redeem or return Apple Gift Cards, App Store & iTunes Gift Cards, or unused Apple Account balance for cash, except as required by law. If your jurisdiction allows for refund of redeemed gift balances, you can [contact Apple Support to request a refund](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase&PGF=PGF63005&category_id=SC0119&symptom_id=20180). When you contact Apple, include the following information:
>
> - Your Apple ID.
> - The refund amount.
> - Your current shipping address.

**P.S.**: Shared link from the Apple India version of the support document.